# Query database from an input form [rails]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a namespaced admin set up where I create Clients and prefill all of their information.  When the client visits the site all they need to do is type in a code that was previously emailed to them, and they can access the site.  The problem I have is that when i create the client, I generate this code.  So it already exists in the db. So when i try to make an input form for the client

using

```
   <%= simple_form_for @client, :method => "get"  do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :code , label: false %>
        <%= f.submit %>
   <% end %>
```

the input field is prepopulated, .. im going to assume it is because it already exists in the database, but really i was to query the db upon submission, and then go on to set up some info in a session variable, .. what am i missing in the form or otherwise to make this a query and not just a prepopulated input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fill in the field yourself so that it's not prepopulated.

`:input_html` key in options allows you to specify attributes for corresponding `<input>` element as said on [the SimpleForm's website, Usage section](http://simple-form.plataformatec.com.br/#usage).

```
<%= f.input :code , label: false, input_html: { value: '' } %>
```